# `ip addr` in one-line per interface

Tags: bash, awk, ip

I would like to print specific information about network configuration for different interfaces over all the servers I manage:

- the interface name
- the interface ipv4 address
- the interface hardware mac address
- …

Unfortunately, a simple `ip -o addr show` doesn't allow to parse easily its output with `awk` because of the line-breaks.

Is it possible to have `ip addr show` printed on *exactly* one line per interface?

Else, is it possible to achieve the same result using `awk` and/or `sed`? This goes beyond my knowledge of those two commands since the lines have to be concatenated tree by tree…

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use --brief flag.

```
ip --brief address show
```

Answer (score 14):

Newer versions of `ip` are able to output JSON formatted data with the `-j` option, which you can then process with a filter such as `jq`.  For example this will print the IPv4 address on the `eth0` interface:

```
$ ip -j addr show dev eth0 | jq -r '.[0].addr_info | map(select(.family == "inet"))[0].local'
192.168.0.1
```

Or to get a list of all IPv4 addresses on the machine, one per line:

```
ip -j addr show | jq -r 'map(.addr_info) | map(map(select(.family == "inet").local)) | flatten | .[]'
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
172.19.0.1
172.17.0.1
172.18.0.1
```

Remove `select(...)` to include IPv6 addresses for example.  Many other variations are possible.

Answer (score 3):

There's `ip -o addr show`, but it prints less information.

Here's a way to massage the output of `ip addr show` into one line per interface. Print a newline before the start of each interface, except at the first line; then print the line content; print a newline at the end of the file.

```
ip addr show |
awk '/^[^ ]/ && NR!=1 {print ""}
     {printf "%s", $0}
     END {print ""}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -nE  '/^[0-9]/! {H;$!d}     # accumulate trailing lines
           x                     # swap new leading line for accumulated gaggle
           s/[^ ]* ([^ ]*).* link\/[^ ]* ([^ ]*).* inet ([^ ]*).*/\1\t\3\t\2/p'
```

and the subst is pretty straightforward, identify and prettyprint 2nd word, word after `link/anything`, word after `inet`

Comment: here, you base yourself on the fact that "link"  appears on the last line, don't you? what if it doesn't?

Comment: Try it, play around with the substitution to see what it's getting and how it breaks things down.  You could try `/eth0/p` for instance to show the eth0 block.`

Answer (score 0):

This `gawk` script will parse `ip addr show` to give you the information you requested. Multiple IPv4 addresses are concatenated with a comma

```
ip a | awk 'function outline() {if (link>"") {printf "%s %s %s\n", iface, inets, link}} $0 ~ /^[1-9]/ {outline(); iface=substr($2, 1, index($2,":")-1); inets=""; link=""} $1 == "link/ether" {link=$2} $1 == "inet" {inet=substr($2, 1, index($2,"/")-1); if (inets>"") inets=inets ","; inets=inets inet} END {outline()}'
```

Splitting this out so it's somewhat more readable,

```
ip addr show |
    awk '
        # Output function to format results (if any)
        function outline() {
            if (link>"") {printf "%s %s %s\n", iface, inets, link}
        }

        # Interface section starts here
        $0 ~ /^[1-9]/ {
            outline();                              # Output anything we previously collected
            iface=substr($2, 1, index($2,":")-1);   # Capture the interface name
            inets="";                               # Reset the list of addresses
            link=""                                 # and MAC too
        }

        # Capture the MAC
        $1 == "link/ether" {
            link=$2                   
        }

        # Capture an IPv4 address. Concatenate to previous with comma
        $1 == "inet" {
            inet=substr($2, 1, index($2,"/")-1);    # Discard /nn subnet mask
            if (inets>"") inets=inets ",";          # Suffix existing list with comma
            inets=inets inet                        # Append this IPv4
        }

        # Input processing has finished
        END {
            outline()                               # Output remaining collection
        }
    '
```

Example output

```
eth0 10.0.2.15 08:00:27:0f:db:b3
eth1 192.168.56.101 08:00:27:33:04:26
```

Answer (score 0):

on debian:

```
man ip
...
       -o, -oneline
              output each record on a single line, replacing line feeds with the '\' character. This is convenient when you want to count records with wc(1) or to grep(1) the output.
```

EDITED@2021.01.06 as i misread the question earlier.

Try this:

```
ip addr show|xargs|sed 's/ \([0-9]*: \)/\n\1/g'
```

Each entry for adapter start with `[0-9]*:`  which could be as a separator for you:

```
root@jprst0202:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.7.11.1/24 brd 10.7.11.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.7.5.1/24 brd 10.7.5.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

So:

- xargs - put everything to single line
- sed... - adds **new line** before each **space**,**number**(or multiple), **colon** and again **space** pattern

Result:

```
root@jprst0202:~# ip addr show|xargs|sed 's/ \([0-9]*: \)/\n\1/g'
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100 link/none inet 10.7.11.1/24 brd 10.7.11.255 scope global tun0 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100 link/none inet 10.7.5.1/24 brd 10.7.5.255 scope global tun1 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100 link/none inet 10.7.7.1/24 brd 10.7.7.255 scope global tun2 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

Comment: From the question, "Unfortunately, a simple ip -o addr show doesn't allow to parse easily its output with awk because of the line-breaks."